# treelistview draw tree on different column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, objectlistview, treelistview

Is it possible to have a TreeListView draw its tree branches on a column other than the first one?

```
TreeListView.TreeRenderer renderer = treeListView2.TreeColumnRenderer;
renderer.LinePen = new Pen(Color.Firebrick, 0.5f);
renderer.Column = treeListView2.AllColumns.ElementAt(2);
renderer.IsShowLines = true;
```

I tried the above; while I am able to adjust the other aspects such as colour and line style, setting the column property doesn't do what I'm hoping/expecting.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve and why? Do you want to draw the root tree in a different column?

Comment: Yes. By default the tree is drawn on the first column. I'd like to be able to draw the tree on a different column if possible.

Comment: I don't think its possible without messing around with the TreeListView internals. WHY do you need it that way? Whats wrong with the first column?

Comment: My use case has me wanting to draw the tree on the second/third column so I can have icons/images showing to the left of the tree.